# Graph of all sets

Tags: graph-theory, set-theory

Working with set theory of ZFC, would it be possible to construct a graph (as in graph theory) with the class of all sets as its nodes? With "is it possible" I mean, would it lead to a contradiction or not?

In particular, I would like to use the graph $(\mathcal{S}, E)$ with S being the class of all sets and $(x,y) \in E \Leftrightarrow x \in y$. Then I would use the property of the graph that there exists a path from one set to another if the first is a "deep" element of the latter.

If this graph is not a legal object, I would also be grateful for possible alternatives for this idea.

Comment: Usually, graphs have a *set* of vertices and a *set* of edges. But nothing prevents you from using (proper) classes instead. Proceed with fingers crossed. Maybe the subgraph having only "everything (possibly deep) in the sets considered" as vertices is enough and more "reliable"?

Comment: Even in set theories with a universal set, there is usually no set $E$ as you describe.

Comment: It is perfectly fine to consider this graph. It will be a proper class, but this does not matter. Here is a cute fact: If you begin with a countable model of set theory, and consider the *undirected graph* where $\{x,y\}\in E$ iff $x\in y$ or $y\in x$, then the resulting graph is the countable random graph.

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen: Since I am only considering one "parent" set, that would just result in a tree, I think. And then the "there exists a path" property would be redundant.

Comment: @ MJD: I'm not sure what makes you say this. In naive set theory, I see no problem with such a definition (apart from the usual ones). Besides, I am aware that E will not be a set but rather a proper class.

Comment: @ Andres Caicedo: Yes, that fact is something which our professor told in the first or second lecture of set theory and I think everyone found this to be funny. One of my favorite cross-topic objects in math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you allow proper classes as graphs, which is not a horrible thing to do since we already allow proper classes as ordered structures, fields, and so on; then you can consider $V$ the class of all sets and $\in$ as $E$ itself (remember that $\in$ is really just a binary relation on $V$).

This is not a graph in the sense that $(V,\in)$ exists, but rather that we have a class that is the class of the vertices, and a class of edges. Do note, however, that this is a directed graph.

But there's a much simpler way to find "deep elements", it's called a transitive closure. If $X$ is a set, we define $\operatorname{TC}(x)$ as the union of $X\cup\bigcup X\cup\bigcup\bigcup X\cup\bigcup\bigcup\bigcup X\cup\ldots$ and this set is exactly those elements which are "deep" elements of $X$.

Moreover, if you are interested in the set $X$, then you can really just talk about the graph defined by $X$ (or rather, it's transitive closure), which is then really a graph that exists since if $X$ is a set, its transitive closure is a set, and $\in$ (restricted to a set) is a set as well.

Comment: Gee, how did I not realize I was redifining E as ∈. Thanks.    

Could you elaborate your second paragraph? What does it mean that the graph does not exist? That it is not the formally correct definition?

For the transitive closure, that is what I am supposed to prove (as an exercise). I have to show that it is the uniquely minimal transitive set which contains $X$.

Comment: When working in a universe of set theory, things exists when they are sets. If something is not a set, then it doesn't exist (in a first-order logic semantics sense of the word). Since $V$ is a proper class and $\in$ is a proper class, there is no ordered pair $(V,\in)$ which is what you usually think of a graph as (an ordered pair of vertices and edges). But we can still talk about it as if it did exist because we can still talk about proper classes, it just requires us to be more careful when we do.

Comment: As for proving a transitive closure exists and it is unique, I think that this is quite the wrong way to approach the problem. Instead working with either the intersection of all transitive sets including $X$ or defining it as the union given above are the correct ways to think about it.

Comment: Thank you, but I do not think there is a "correct" way to prove something. Maybe your proposal might be more intuitive for most people, however, using the graph I described was the first idea that came to my mind.

Comment: You are right, there is no correct way. And it's nice to play with concepts that you came up with. But maybe you can listen to someone that has been doing these things quite longer than you have (if you are looking for this proof, then most probably you just began with set theory), and maybe that someone has more intuition about set theory and sets than you do, and when they say "correct" they mean that in the philosophical sense of how to think about the transitive closure. But hey, you do whatever you want.